# How to help visitors on Meta distinguish more clearly Meta reputation and Stack Overflow reputation?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, meta

One gets easily confused seeing many people on Meta with 30k, 40k, or 45k reputation. For a while one may mistakenly think they must be really smart, brainy, and experienced. Until he checks out their Stack Overflow reputation which could be peanuts compared to that! It's only then that one gets the real idea about them, after they have been taken for a ride. How can we prevent this on Meta? Should both reputations be displayed side-by-side? After all, reputation on Meta is not even remotely comparable with that on Stack Overflow as Meta is basically a chat/small-talk site where you give wordy answers and it doesn't take much talent to do that, while in Stack Overflow things are so strict and rigorous.

Comment: It might be time to take a break from Meta.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Yes PhaDaphunk,it's the `Let's provide lip-service when we can't come up with one ourself` thing as I can see.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Glad you checked my whole history on `stack exchange` but missed it that I joined yesterday.Hmnnn....

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying

Comment: @random Not worth it.Trying to get points here I mean.

Comment: As the kids say nowadays, LOL WUT?

Comment: @animuson Thatisa great editcomment :P

Comment: Between this question and [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178067/what-does-a-1000-stackoverflow-reputation-in-2-months-due-to-qa-over-a-single), I think you're getting way too hung up over the meaning of reputation.

Answer (score 11):

You can't compare both reputations because they don't represent the same thing **at all**. It's like comparing reputation on `Arqade` with reputation on `Stack Overflow`. It would like saying:

> Hey this guy knows a lot about video games so it gives him a lot of C# notoriety

Questions on meta are about the community, the site in general, bug reports, feature requests or even winter hats...

I strongly recommand you read both [Meta's FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) and [Stack Overflow's FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) so you catch all the differences between the two sites.

Comment: Who knows you might just get me another `reversal` badge :)

Comment: @HamacherGalvin: Well, I have 44k rep here and I completely agree. Also, you have to keep in mind that currently Meta Stack Overflow serves as the meta for the *entire* Stack Exchange network, not just Stack Overflow, so questions posted here may not even be relevant to Stack Overflow at heart, but the network in general. PS, with that attitude, I don't see you passing anyone's reputation any time soon, especially not when you write sentences with everything in `inline code blocks` and withmissingspaces.